# How to follow up with a professor who had received my transcripts but did not reply?

Tags: etiquette, professorship

I inquired a professor at a reputable university regarding the per-requisite for his research group and if a certain knowledge is required, with a CV of mine. He asked for my transcripts. I mailed him my transcripts but have not got any reply yet. It has been 4 days.

How should I approach the matter?

Answer (score 3):

Keep waiting.  4 days is not very long.  If you have not heard anything in 3-4 weeks, send another email asking politely if he has had a chance to think about your request.

Comment: 3-4 weeks is a little long. I'd say 1 week to 10 days.

Answer (score 2):

In my "career" in academia, I have found that some professors will only reply if they want you. On the other hand, four days is usually not enough time to warrant emailing the professor again. I would wait at least 10 days.

Sad to say, professors sometimes will not be bothered by tying up all the loose ends of research assistant, lab help, etc. type jobs they offer. They find their person and move on. I have had professors reply (very belatedly) to my inquiries about applications with terse emails like "I don't need you currently," or "The position's filled."

I would email the professor a week from now. If he still does not reply, he probably has deemed you unworthy of his time.